# EntityDataSource with a GridView WHERE Explnation

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Hi I use a GridView with an EntityDataSource.

I need to FILTER data from EntityDataSource using WHERE.
The Filter should use the ProviderUserKey (GUID DataType in my case) for the Current logged in User.

At the moment I use to retrive my Guid this code in Page_Load Event

```
Guid myActiveUser = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

- How to pass this variable to EntityDataSource "Where" for filtering and siplay the result in my GridView?
- It is this the right way to do it? Any other solution?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the code like the following:

```
Guid myActiveUser = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;    
EntityDataSource1.Where = "it.User = " + myActiveUser.ToString();
```